# How would this Linq query with Join be written as a Lambda?

Tags: vb.net, lambda, entity-framework-6

I am trying to learn how to do joins as lambdas and I have this linq query but cannot figure out how to do it as a lambda

```
From posts In db.be_Posts Join t In db.be_PostTag On posts.PostID 
Equals t.PostID Where t.Tag = tag Select posts.Title
```

The above Join works in LinqPad. And this is what I have so far as a lambda. I am also trying to put everything into the viewmodel.

```
db.be_Posts.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.DateCreated).Join(db.be_PostTag, 
Function(p) p.PostID, Function(t) t.PostID, Function(p, t).Select(Function(p1) 
New be_PostsViewModel
With {.Id =
```

I don't get an intellisense after `.Id` when I type either p, p1 or t. What am i doing wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This part looks very weird (intended or typo?) :

```
....Function(p, t).Select(Function(p1)...
```

Something like this should work as far as I can see :

```
db.be_Posts.
    OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.DateCreated).
    Join(db.be_PostTag, _
            Function(p) p.PostID, _
            Function(t) t.PostID, _
            Function(p, t) New be_PostsViewModel With 
                            {
                                .Id = p.PostID,
                                ....
                                ....
                            })
```

And your LINQ query syntax can be translated to method syntax like this :

```
db.be_Posts.
    Join(db.be_PostTag, _
            Function(p) p.PostID, _
            Function(t) t.PostID, _
            Function(p, t) p.Title)
```